# Digital Logic design(Logic Gates)

Tags: digital-logic

If more than two inputs AND & OR gates are available, how will we connect its inputs so that they work as 2 input gates? Perform it for 3 and 4 input AND & OR gates.

How it will be done?

Comment: Can you create a truth table for a 3-input or 4-input gate?

Comment: yes, of course..

Comment: If you compare the truth table for a 2-input gate, what should happen to the unused inputs?

Comment: You have several options- tie to '1', tie to '0' or something else.

Comment: But how will we connect its inputs so that they work as 2 input gates? What would be its authentic answer?

Comment: There are 2 answers that are valid.

Comment: Any one who can make the answer more clear??Remember that we have to use all the inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Your Question is bit Ambiguous. 
If you mean that you have 3 input And gate or 3/(more then 3) input OR gate how to use it as just two input?

It can be done

In case of OR gate just connect any extra inputs to 0, so A|B|0 = A|B;

and if you have AND gate then just connect extra inputs with 1, so A&B&1 = A&B;

for example

[image]

Comment: your answer is not clear.

Comment: now see the circuit diagram.

Answer (score 0):

For an AND  gate or an OR gate a logical signal can connect to a "spare" input.

A and A and B and B equals A and B.

A or A or B or B equals A or B.

Or just tie unused inputs to 1 for an AND gate or 0 for an OR gate.